# How to create a screen with a condition in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need a little help with flutter. I want to make a screen with a condition. The condition is if we have data show that data from firebase but if we don't have data show a button that says add data. The codes below show data from firebase but when we have no data that shows nothing.

Here are my codes that show a black screen.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<MapLogic>(
      builder: (mapLogic) => Scaffold(
        // backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream:
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                if (snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        generalController.focusOut(context);
                        Get.to(const AddNewVehicle());
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 55,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Styles.primaryColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Styles.primaryColor.withOpacity(0.19),
                              blurRadius: 40,
                              spreadRadius: 0,
                              offset: const Offset(
                                  0, 22), // changes position of shadow
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Add A Vehicle",
                            // style: state.buttonTextStyle
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return FadedSlideAnimation(
                    child: Wrap(
                      children:
                          List.generate(snapshot.data!.docs.length, (index) {
                        if (snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('driver_id') ==
                            mapLogic.currentDriverData?.get('id')) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 30, 15, 0),
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(19),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: customThemeColor.withOpacity(0.19),
                                      blurRadius: 40,
                                      spreadRadius: 0,
                                      offset: const Offset(
                                          0, 22), // changes position of shadow
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      ///---image
                                      Hero(
                                        tag:
                                            '${snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('image')}',
                                        child: Material(
                                          child: Container(
                                            height: 80,
                                            width: 80,
                                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.grey,
                                                shape: BoxShape.circle),
                                            child: ClipRRect(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(40),
                                              child: Image.network(
                                                '${snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('image')}',
                                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),


                                                  ///---price
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Align(
                                                      alignment:
                                                          Alignment.center,
                                                      child: Container(
                                                        width: 70,
                                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                            borderRadius:
                                                                BorderRadius
                                                                    .circular(
                                                                        19),
                                                            color:
                                                                customThemeColor),
                                                        child: Padding(
                                                          padding:
                                                              const EdgeInsets
                                                                      .fromLTRB(
                                                                  0, 2, 0, 2),
                                                          child: Center(
                                                            child: Text(
                                                                '\$${snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('dis_price')}',
                                                                style: state
                                                                    .priceTextStyle!
                                                                    .copyWith(
                                                                        color: Colors
                                                                            .white)),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ))
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return const SizedBox();
                        }
                      }),
                    ),
                    beginOffset: const Offset(0, 0.3),
                    endOffset: const Offset(0, 0),
                    slideCurve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
                  );
                }
              } else {
                return Text(
                  'Record not found',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                );
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this pattern but I will suggest following [docs' one](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

```dart
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
      !snapshot.hasData) {
    return Text("could not find any data");
  }
  if (snapshot.hasData) {...}
  if (snapshot.hasError) return Text("error");
  return CircularProgressIndicator();
}
```

Comment: glad to help, make sure to check the docs for better understanding